# Window resize slowly and freeze with compton, openbox and catalyst-hoo

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, openbox, ati

I'm try for the second time use Arch Linux.

In this installation I get:

- openbox
- tint2
- compton
- catalyst-hook (Vi0L0's)

After starting the compton, I can not see what I'm typing in the terminal, videos (flash/html) freeze in fullscreen, teamviewer stops working and resize any window is extremely slow.

If I kill compton, everything it's work BUT resize keep slow.

How can I fix that?

**~/config/compton.conf**

```
backend = "glx";
paint-on-overlay = true;
glx-no-stencil = true;
glx-no-rebind-pixmap = true;
refresh-rate = "60";
vsync="none"

# Shadow
shadow = false;
no-dock-shadow = true;     # Avoid drawing shadows on dock/panel windows.
no-dnd-shadow = true;  # Don't draw shadows on DND windows.
shadow-exclude = [ "n:w:*Firefox*" ]; # Not sure what it does or if it works

# Fading
fading = false;
no-fading-openclose = true
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
   Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
   Option       "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
   Option       "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
   Option       "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
   Driver      "fglrx"
   BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
   Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
   Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
   DefaultDepth     24
   SubSection "Display"
      Viewport   0 0
      Depth     24
   EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh**

```
tint2 &
sh ~/.fehbg &
conky -c ~/.conky/conkyrc_grey &
compton --backend glx --paint-on-overlay --glx-no-stencil --vsync opengl-swc --shadow-e
xclude "! name~=''" --config ~/.config/compton.conf -b &
pulseaudio --start &
```

**~/.xinitrc**

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ]; then
  for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/*; do
    [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
  done
  unset f
fi

# exec gnome-session
# exec startkde
# exec startxfce4
# ...or the Window Manager of your choice
exec openbox-session
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an ATI Radeon HD 6310.

This are the compton.conf settings I use:

```
backend = "glx";
paint-on-overlay = false;
glx-no-stencil = true;
refresh-rate = 0;
vsync = "opengl-mswc";
```

They work very well. Maybe they help you too?

Comment: Thanks for you answer my friend, but I leave the arch linux for a while and buy a macbook pro. Anyway, thanks!